# price earning ratio and expected future profit

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

The P/E or price to earning ratio is a common tool to judge the relative price of shares. The trouble is that a high P/E ratio could be a sign of an overvalued stock but it could also just mean that the expected future profits are very big. So current profits are low relative to the stock price but the market expects that profits will be growing and relative to these future profits the current stock price is more reasonable.

My question is whether there are some investment guides that try to put these future expectations into some concrete formulas that allow you transform the P/E ratios into expected future profits or some expected growth rate of the current profits or something like that.

So with example numbers, company A made $100 million profit last year and has a total market value of $2 billion for a P/E ratio of 20. Company B also made $100 million profit last year but has a total market value of $4 billion for a P/E ratio of 40. Let's assume that the general expectation is that profits for company A will stay mostly constant for the foreseeable future. Profits in company B are expected to grow but can one put a number on that based on the current stock price (possibly relative to company A)?

The idea is to use this number and compare with my personal beliefs about the future growth potential to decide which stock to buy. Of course that still requires predictions about the future but it seems judging whether company B's profit will increase by more or less than say 20% per year for the next 5 years seems more tangible that judging whether a P/E ratio of 40 is too high or too low.

I'm pretty sure others must have had this idea before so some reference to a named investment strategy trying to do that or something like that would be very useful as well.